# OFBiz hangs for unknown reasons

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ofbiz

I have downloaded Apache OFBiz 16 on a machine, unzipped it in a directory, loaded default data using `loadDefault` option of `gradlew`.

After that I ran ofbiz using `gradlew ofbiz`. Doing this successfully runs the ofbiz and I can access the application from localhost as well as from the other machines on the same network using `http://IP:8080/appname` and `https://IP:8443/appname`.

But after some period of time, ofbiz hangs and the requests no longer seem to be completed and they seem to be loading for ever. It seems to me that problem arises when I access the OFBiz on https but problem starts to appear after some time of deployment. Initially both http and https seems to work fine.

Can anyone point out, what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please share your server logs when the request stuck into infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ofbiz uses

> DelegatorFactory.getDelegator()

to find/create asynchronously in database using a single daemon thread. When the base delegator is intially absent, ofbiz will block trying to create one by using the same daemon thread--which is already being used. Hence, ofbiz is deadlocked.

*** Please  share your server logs***